# Sending image as base64string to view, uri too long exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, get

I have http get action that sends some user information from database, including small image(around 100kb) even thought I understand its not the best solution, I store it in byte[] and convert to base64string before sending it to view. This string is part of viewModel, I dont send it directly with url. When the length of the string is under 30k characters It does work, but as it goes near 100k i get exception: "**Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long**". How is my viewModel property bidden with uri length? And what can be possible workaround?

`var viewModel = new UserViewModel(){ Image = Convert.ToBase64String(user.Image)};
return View(viewModel);`

Any information would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use an HTTP POST instead and put the image in the body, that's what it's for.

Comment: But why does property of viewModel impact uri?

Comment: Can you post what your URI looks like?

Comment: http://localhost:1234/User/Edit

Comment: Did you tag your Action method with [HttpPost]  ?  The maximum length of a Uri is around 2000 characters (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Comment: I know its gonna work that way, I'm curious why can't I send it using httpget? How is uri (http://localhost:1234/User/Edit) more than 2000?

Comment: Because the Image property of your viewModel is returned in the URI e.g. http://localhost:1234/User/Edit?Image={randomHexStringHereThatsTooLong}

Comment: Yes, I figured it out, thanks. So, I have to use httppost or send image as some other type?

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, I don't even know what I'm talking about. As long as the Image is not an argument into your action method it should not be in the URL.